# Style something only on the home page

Tags: css, homepage

I am relatively new to Wordpress, but I'm sure there's a way to do what I'd like to do.

I have a container in my template, and on the home page I'd like to specify slightly different padding to this element.

My current CSS is as follows:

```
#main_content .container {
position: relative;
padding: 120px 0;
}
```

I'd like to bring the padding down to 80px if I'm on the Home page, otherwise keep it that way.

Is this something I'd have to do within the template or are there fancy 'WordPress only' CSS tricks that I am currently unaware of?

In my limited experience, I think I should be able to specify whether or not the page `is_home` or similar, and select a custom stylesheet in the `header.php` file for the home page. Presumably, with `!important` after my padding change for the CSS.

Can I get some direction? The results I'm finding through searching aren't particularly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WordPress [`body_class($class)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) is a nice dynamic way to load styles, js for specific body contents. If your theme doesn't support body class add them very simply:

- Open the `header.php` (or the template that contains the `<body>` tag)
- Edit the `<body>` tag and make it to `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` — you are Done! :)

Now when you are in:

- `Home` page, your body tag will render `<body class="blog">`
- `Front Page`, your body tag will render `<body class="home">`
- Blog post detail page (`single.php`), your body tag will render `<body class="single">`
- Page detail page (`page.php`), your body tag will render `<body class="page">`

So, you are free now. Style however you want. For external stylesheet, and for home page your style will be (@saifur already mentioned):

```
body.home #main_content .container {
   position: relative;
   padding: 120px 0;
}
```

#### Internal CSS

For internal CSS, there is a conditional checker in WordPress, called [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home), and another is [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page). With these two, you can check whether "you" are in home page or in front page, and then can load your internal CSS code:

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
<style id="my-internal-css">
    #main_content .container {
       position: relative;
       padding: 120px 0;
    }
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Similarly `is_single()`, `is_page()`, `is_category()`, `is_archive()`, `is_day()`, ... so on...

Comment: Your answer was very helpful and thorough, thank you!

Comment: If you are in `Home` page, your body tag will render <body class="blog"> instead of `home` and in `Front Page` <body class="home"> instead `front-page`: 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L570

Comment: @mayeenul Islam, i have applied some css on ".page" class for my inner pages. But my home page is having both ".home" & ".page" classes. How should i handle this?

Comment: what i have found is "page-template-default" class in available on all inner pages except home page, so used that. Thanks anyway.. it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check the class of body tag, there is a class named home for home page. I hope the following css will help you.

```
.home #main_content .container {
position: relative;
padding: 120px 0;
}
```